# Exercise 4 of chapter 2 of Do carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume $(U,x)$ is a coordinate with $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \}$ is orthonormal basis. Let $c=(c_1(t),c_2(t))\in M^2$ and $V=V^i \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$. What I do :

(a) since $V$ is parallel, we have 
$$
0= \frac{DV}{dt}= (\frac{dV^k}{dt}+ \frac{dc_i}{dt}V^j\Gamma_{ij}^k )\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}
$$
So, there is 
$$
\langle \frac{dV}{dt}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}  \rangle  = - \frac{dc_i}{dt} V^j \Gamma_{ij}^k
$$
for normal coordinates, we have $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$ ? (I am not sure). So, we have 
$$
\langle \frac{dV}{dt}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}  \rangle  = 0
$$
if the above process is right, obviously, it depends the coordinate. And for general coordinate, the above process is not right.

(b) Consider parametrized 
$$
\gamma : \theta \rightarrow S^2  ~~~\theta\rightarrow (\cos\theta, \sin\theta, 0)
$$
So, the velocity is 
$$
V=(-\sin\theta, \cos \theta, 0)
$$
Then to calculate $\frac{DV}{dt}$. I think I　should choice a suitable coordinate on $S^2$. But

> [image]

Comment: Do you know how $\nabla _X Y$ looks in the case of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @FriederJäckel  Do you mean $\nabla_X Y$ is the tangential component of $\overline \nabla _X Y$, where $\overline \nabla$ is connection of $\mathbb R^3$. But  how to use this to calculate ?

Comment: Exactly $\nabla _X Y$ is the tangential component of the usual derivative in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ So can you figure out how $\frac{D V}{dt}$ looks like?